# Is it possible to fake JavaScript sensor events that fire on window object?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

JavaScript supports multiple event types for measuring mobile device sensors. These events fire on the *window* object e.g.

```js
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", function () {
  // do something with device orientation
}, true);

window.addEventListener("devicemotion", function () {
  // do something with acceleration
}, true);
```

When such an event fires, can you be sure that the browser itself (and hence the user ultimately) was the source of the event or is it possible for another script to generate such events?

In other words, developer tools aside, could a third-party script from a different source entirely (e.g. an ad or analytics script) create events that appear to be from a hardware sensor?

Comment: Can you please explain more clearly what you mean by _"or is it possible for another script to generate such events"_? The script of your document is your, hence you are the one including it. Unless you are manually firing that event you're sure that the user is the source. Besides, even by using the developer tools, you can surely fire that event manually but, as long as the user is not including third-party script through some third-party tools you can be 100% sure that the user **is** the source and will always be.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, tried to clarify question a little.

Comment: Technically yes, a third-party script could do that, but I don't think that any relevant analytics script will do that or, if it will, it won't significantly impact your script, hence you should not be worried about that: just be careful when you include external scripts and be sure that the sources are fine. That said, both ADs and Analytics probably won't do that, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You can fake these sensor readings using Chrome's dev tools and for an advanced JavaScript programmer it should be not a big problem to overwrite the internal methods responsible for this, but it would be much easier to just take your code and change it, so it doesn't matter what sensor events are transmitted.

Short version: No you cannot be sure, but it takes some knowledge to fake this.

Comment: I think you've gotten to the nub of the question: dev tools aside, can one overwrite the internal methods responsible for generating these events? Seems like you shouldn't be allowed to.

Comment: I think that's part of the power of JavaScript and why we're still using this messy language with so many strange quirks after all these years. It is extremely flexible which gives you as a developer much freedom, but also the possibility to mess it up really hard.
In the end everything is executed on the users device and therefore everything can be faked, if someone really wants to do this.